# How to refresh token with iOS SDK

Tags: oauth2, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Im using the code :

```
SFOAuthCredentials *cred = [SFRestAPI sharedInstance].coordinator.credentials;
NSString *instanceUrl = cred.instanceUrl.absoluteString;
NSString *accessToken = cred.accessToken;
NSString *path =  @"/services/oauth2/token";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", instanceUrl, path];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setObject:@"refresh_token" forKey:@"grant_type"];
[parameters setObject:cred.clientId forKey:@"client_id"];
[parameters setObject:cred.refreshToken forKey:@"refresh_token"];
NSLog(@"Parameter refresh %@",parameters);

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[manager POST:url parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * Nonnull task, id  Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  _Nullable task, NSError  _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

But its always return error :

`Mikimoto_AccountInput[438:68914] Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17023ae60> { URL: https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store";
    "Content-Security-Policy" = "referrer origin-when-cross-origin";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 09 Feb 2017 04:03:57 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-ReadOnlyMode" = false;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226572 726f7222 3a22756e 73757070 6f727465 645f6772 616e745f 74797065 222c2265 72726f72 5f646573 63726970 74696f6e 223a2267 72616e74 20747970 65206e6f 74207375 70706f72 74656422 7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}`

Im stucking with this can you guys help me thanks.